# Interval between Enemy Shots

Tags: artificial-intelligence, unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

I am working on a simple project that will serve as pillar to future ones.

My problem is. When I move from my "Seeking" state to my "attacking" state, I check if I am within the enemies fire range. If I am, it shoots at me. To do this I placed a call to the function 'FireRocket' inside the ' if(Enemy != none && VSize(Location - Enemy.Location) < AttackDistance)' statement. This works perfectly but, as expected, a tone of missiles are fired per second (since this code is inside a 'tick function). To avoid this, I tried to use SetTimer (SetTimer(FireInterval, true, 'FireRocket');) and this is when my problem came up.

Now, the timer only starts counting when I move OUT of range of the enemy and he does indeed fire, but again, only when I am OUTSIDE of its range. When I come back to its range parameters, he stops firing at me...

The problem is on the "ATTACKING" state.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
class AwesomeRangedBoss extends AwesomeEnemy
placeable;

var float FireInterval;

////EVENTS////

auto state Seeking
{
    function Tick(float Deltatime)
    {
        local vector NewLocation;

        if(Enemy == none)
        {
            GetEnemy();
        }

        else if(VSize(Location - Enemy.Location) < FollowDistance)
        {
            NewLocation = Location;
            NewLocation += normal(Enemy.Location - Location) * MovementSpeed * DeltaTime;
            SetLocation(NewLocation);

            if(VSize(NewLocation - Enemy.Location) < AttackDistance)
            {
                GoToState('Attacking');
            }
        }
    }
}

state Attacking
{
    function Tick(float Deltatime)
    {
        if(Enemy == none)
        {
            GetEnemy();
        }

        if(Enemy != none && VSize(Location - Enemy.Location) < AttackDistance)
        {
            //SetTimer(FireInterval, true, 'FireRocket');
            //FireRocket();
        }
        if(VSize(Location - Enemy.Location) > AttackDistance)
        {
            GoToState('Seeking');
        }
    }
}

/////////////////////////
function FireRocket()
{
    local UTProj_Rocket MyRocket;
    `log("BOOM!");

    MyRocket = spawn(class'UTProj_Rocket', self,, Location);
    MyRocket.Init(normal(Enemy.Location - Location));

    MyMesh.SetMaterial(0, AttackingMat);
    SetTimer(1, false, 'EndAttack');
}

event TakeDamage(int DamageAmount, Controller EventInstigator,
 vector HitLocation, vector Momentum, class<DamageType> DamageType,
optional TraceHitInfo HitInfo, optional Actor DamageCauser)
{
  Health--;

  if(Health == 0 && EventInstigator != none &&
EventInstigator.PlayerReplicationInfo != none)
    {
        WorldInfo.Game.ScoreObjective(EventInstigator.PlayerReplicationInfo, 1);

        Destroy();
    }
}

defaultproperties
{
    BumpDamage = 15.0

    MovementSpeed = 256
    FollowDistance = 1512
    AttackDistance = 1024
    Health = 5
    FireInterval = 1

    Begin Object Name=EnemyMesh
        Scale3D=(X=1.0, Y=1.0, Z=2.0)
    End Object

    Begin Object Name=CollisionCylinder
        CollisionRadius=128.0
        CollisionHeight=256.0
    End Object
}
```

Comment: if you've solved the problem you should post it as an answer

Comment: Just did. Thank you for the headsup :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Here is the edited code. Now shots are properly fired with a 1second interval.

```
state Attacking
{
    function Tick(float Deltatime)
    {
        //HasFired = true;

        if(Enemy == none)
        {
            GetEnemy();
        }

        if(Enemy != none && VSize(Location - Enemy.Location) < AttackDistance)
        {
            ShootRocket();
        }
        if(VSize(Location - Enemy.Location) > AttackDistance)
        {
            GoToState('Seeking');
        }
    }
}

/////////////////////////
function ShootRocket()
{
    local UTProj_Rocket MyRocket;

    if(Enemy != none && VSize(Location - Enemy.Location) < AttackDistance && HasFired == false)
    {
        `log("BOOM!");

        MyRocket = spawn(class'UTProj_Rocket', self,, Location);
        MyRocket.Init(normal(Enemy.Location - Location));

        MyMesh.SetMaterial(0, AttackingMat);
        SetTimer(1, false, 'EndAttack');

       HasFired = true;

        if(HasFired == true)
        {
            SetTimer(FireInterval, false, 'IsAttacking');
        }
    }
}

function IsAttacking()
{
    HasFired = false;
    GoToState('Attacking');
}
```